# Преобразование строки с разделителями в многомерный массив

Tags: массивы, php, строки

На небольшом примере как по идее все должно работать.

```
#есть листинг файла config.php
return array
(
    'db' => array
    (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'name' => 'some_db_name'
        //etc
    )
);

#класс
class Config
{
    public static function get($name)
    {
        //Подключаем файл
        $config = include('config.php');

        //тут должна быть вся магия разбора строки
        //чтобы при вызове Config::get('db.host');
        //сформировался доступ к элеменам масива вида $config['db']['host'];
    }
}
```

Вложенность индексов может быть разная, в данном случае вложенность равна двум.

Для себя хочу понять просто принцип реализации, разбиения строки имея разделители и создание из количества полученных элементов, из которых сформируется доступ к элементам многомерного массива.

З.Ы. Надеюсь понятно изъяснил суть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простейший, наверно, вариант:

```
private static $configuration = array();
public static function get($name = '')
{
  // получение конфигурации
  // ...
  // достаем значение
  $var = self::$configuration;
  if (!empty($name))
    foreach (explode('.', $name) as $part) {
      if (!isset($var[$part]))
        return NULL;
      $var = $var[$part];
    }
  return $var;
}
```

Соответственно, возвращает значение переменной или NULL, если не нашел ее.

При вызове `Config::get()` вернет всю конфигурацию, при `Config::get('db.host')` вернет `Cofig::$configuration['db']['host']`.

Comment: Все предельно просто. Увы более сложнее начал подходить к решению в чем и потерпел фиаско. Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

1. Разбиваем строку с помощью explode
2. Делаем копию массива
3. Используя массив полученных ключей, продвигаемся по копии массива, перезаписывая переменную
4. Стреляем ошибкой в случае неуспеха
5. Возвращаем то, что находится в промежуточной переменной

https://gist.github.com/etki/f8df18316ea25d1bddda